# Copy folder contents in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, drag-and-drop

Strange issue: I want to copy "model" folder in Xcode, I am able to copy it and can see in Xcode and hit "show in finder"

1.I tried by select folder and drag and drop into Xcode.

2.Select project "Add files to project"

It works in original project (Check "model" folder colour(Blue)) App works fine.

[image]

Now, check my newly created project when I tried above steps,

[image]

it show's yellow colour now I am getting a crash that not getting load files. Where I am wrong ? any help

Comment: did you check "copy items" when adding the folder?

Comment: @fabersky.Yep i tried that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe its reference issue of Create groups or create folder references while drag and drop or add files to your project. please check maybe its solved your issue.

Comment: Or you can try to add your folder contents (.h or .m) files into Targets/Build Phases/Compile Sources

Comment: You are correct by selecting "create folder references" works fine.thanks.